# How to display messages in Thymeleaf and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I created a Spring Boot web application that uses Thymeleaf as the template engine. I configured the `MessageSource` to look for messages in a subfolder:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

    messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);

    return messageSource;
}
```

In this folder I created the file `messages_de.properties` with the content `ticket.type.BUG=Fehler`. In my template I try to display the text like this:

```
<p th:text="#{ticket.type.BUG}">BUG</p>
```

But when the page is rendered, I get the following:

```
<p>??ticket.type.BUG_de_DE??</p>
```

What am I missing? Do I have to configure any additional beans?

**P.S.:**

On the 'server side' I am able to obtain the message using `MessageSource#getMessage("ticket.type.BUG", null, Locale.GERMANY)`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because I am using Spring Boot, the `MessageSource` is configured with a [`MessageSourceAutoConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.html). These settings can be easily changed in the `application.properties` file. In my case I had to add the following to this file:

```
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages
```

Comment: This is clever. I though `spring.messages.basename` only refers to the prefix for each file. Didn't know it included the folders.

Comment: I have the same problem and has this configuration,but this does not work for me..

Answer (score 4):

And add this to your `application.properties` file

```
#messages
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages
```

and store the file n the correct folder as specified above.

you don't need `messageSource` bean

Comment: Sorry. I din't see that. Btw next time you can select that as an answer, so it will be visible for us clearly. And you don't have to down-voting an effort on helping.

Answer (score 3):

The way I resolved the i18n messaging was to define the `MessagesSource` bean like you. Additionally I had to override the `getValidator()` method of the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setValidationMessageSource( messageSource() );
    return validator;
}
```

After this, it worked for me.

Comment: This does not solve it for me and I don't know why it should. This configuration has something to do with JSR-303 validation which I don't use.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a file `messages.properties` (no `_de`) present to allow fallback? Does it work? Is your browser set to locale `DE_de` ?

Comment: Yes (english). No. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The message source be relative to classpath:

```
messageSource.setBasename("  classpath:i18n/messages");
```

Here is a tutorial I referenced for thymeleaf and spring = http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html

Comment: I don't think so. I have updated my question. When I prepend 'classpath:' I am not able to obtain messages in the Java code, too.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. In my case faraj's method worked. But I wondered why I couldn't do it with the bean configuration. And my code was:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource getMessageResource()  {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageResource= new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageResource.setBasename("localization/messages");
    messageResource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageResource;
}
```

Then it occurred to me that the method name would be the bean name by default. so my bean name was getMessageResource. I thought that this naming might be a problem in configuration, so I named the bean myself. Like this:

```
@Bean("messageSource")
public MessageSource getMessageResource()  {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageResource= new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageResource.setBasename("localization/messages");
    messageResource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageResource;
}
```

So it was solved without making any other changes and without any configuration to the properties file.

I am attaching the whole class as an example:

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new CookieLocaleResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean("messageSource")
    public MessageSource getMessageResource()  {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageResource= new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageResource.setBasename("localization/messages");
        messageResource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageResource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

My resource file structure:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MglWU.png)

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34894846)