# Thymeleaf + Spring (not Boot) - how to show messages from messageSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble setting up my Spring MVC (not using Boot, because I started it prior to discovering Spring Initializr) with Thymeleaf to show messages from my resource bundle.

Main configuration class for the app is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "b.c.m.h")
public class HrmConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect(new GroupingStrategy()));
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);
        viewResolver.setCache(false);

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {

        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        SessionLocaleResolver  resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
        return resolver;
    } 

    @Bean
    public UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver() {
        return new UrlTemplateResolver();
    }

    // other beans and configs
}
```

The general view of the application is:

[image]

And the messages_pt_BR.properties file is:

```
#messages
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages

app.name=APPLICATION NAME
```

But, when I try to show the `APPLICATION NAME` somewhere on the page, with this:

```
<p th:text="#{app.name}">app.name</p>
```

I get only

```
??app.name_pt_BR??
```

I have browsed a number of possible solutions and tutorials, including:

[I18n in Spring boot + Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531131/i18n-in-spring-boot-thymeleaf)
http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n-annotation-example
[How to display messages in Thymeleaf and Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532172/how-to-display-messages-in-thymeleaf-and-spring-boot)

Still I cannot get it working.

Browser and OS are set to locale en_US.

How to get tihs solved?

Comment: Check if the file in src/main/resources/messages_pt_br.properties have the same content. Spring take the one in this specific folder

Comment: Hassam, thanks for your input, but I got no luck still with this.

Comment: Still stuck with it ?

Comment: yeah! no luck still...

Comment: what version of Spring and Thymeleaf?

Comment: Spring 4.1.6, Thymeleaf 2.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem on this question:

[Spring 4 with thymeleaf Internationalization not identify message from resource properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159685/spring-4-with-thymeleaf-internationalization-not-identify-message-from-resource?rq=1)

Basically, what solved the issue was to separate the following `@Bean` ...

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect(new GroupingStrategy()));
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);
    viewResolver.setCache(false);

    return viewResolver;
}
```

... into three distinct beans like:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setPrefix(HTML_VIEWS);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect(new GroupingStrategy()));
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    viewResolver.setCache(false);
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);

    return viewResolver;
}
```

From that, I got it working as I expected.

Thanks for the insights and help!

Answer (score 5):

Working with Spring Boot here, but I was able to reproduce your issue and it's tied to the `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` once I changed it to `ResourceBundleMessageSource` it worked like it should.

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {

    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("/i18n/messages");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    return messageSource;
}
```

**Update:**

Found that you need to provide full pathing for the ReloadableReourceBundleMessageSource so if your `/il8n` directory is within your  classpath you need to set your basename to `classpath:/il8n/messages`

see my post here: [Why does Thymeleaf International only works with ResourceBundleMessageSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816274)

Comment: @gtludwig modified the answer to what found to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Bean(name="localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        SessionLocaleResolver  resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        resolver.resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        return resolver;
    }
```

changed your localresolver bean this might help you . if you have the browser set up to `en locale` how come the application read the `pt_BR` change that to `_en` in the msg properties file

or you can change your browser locale to `Portuguese - BRAZIL (BR) (pt_BR)` without changing code in anywhere

Comment: have u tried changing browser locale to portugeese-brazil ?. without changing anything