# Why does Thymeleaf International only works with ResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

So in helping answer This question [Thymeleaf + Spring (not Boot) - how to show messages from messageSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752665/thymeleaf-spring-not-boot-how-to-show-messages-from-messagesource/36754016#36754016)

I found that if you use the `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` it wouldn't working. Thymeleaf would display ??app.name_pt_BR?? instead of the expected result.

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {

    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("/i18n/messages");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    return messageSource;
}
```

when I switch to the below it worked as expected.

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {

    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("/i18n/messages");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    return messageSource;
}
```

Why is the ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource not able to be use?

adding code for this question: [GitHub](https://github.com/ohiocowboy/stackoverflow/tree/master/36816274)

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem with XML based configuration.  Sample application available on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/36816274).  Something seems to be off with the Java based configuration.  There are [other examples](https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/spring-mvc-full-java-based-config/) using Java config that use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` successfully.

Comment: Interesting... I see where you are using Thymeleaf, but the example you linked isn't. But both are not using Spring Boot. I under if that is where the issue is.

Comment: May be worth raising an issue in the Spring Github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer!

Per the javadocs for `ReloadableResouceBundleMessageSource`

Spring-specific MessageSource implementation that accesses resource bundles using specified basenames, participating in the Spring ApplicationContext's resource loading.
In contrast to the JDK-based ResourceBundleMessageSource, this class uses Properties instances as its custom data structure for messages, loading them via a PropertiesPersister strategy from Spring Resource handles. This strategy is not only capable of reloading files based on timestamp changes, but also of loading properties files with a specific character encoding. It will detect XML property files as well.

**Note that the basenames set as "basenames" property are treated in a slightly different fashion than the "basenames" property of ResourceBundleMessageSource. It follows the basic ResourceBundle rule of not specifying file extension or language codes, but can refer to any Spring resource location (instead of being restricted to classpath resources). With a "classpath:" prefix, resources can still be loaded from the classpath, but "cacheSeconds" values other than "-1" (caching forever) might not work reliably in this case.**

For a typical web application, message files could be placed into WEB-INF: e.g. a "WEB-INF/messages" basename would fine a "WEB-INF/messages.properties", "WEB-INF/messages_en.properties" etc arrangement as well as "WEB-INF/messages.xml", "WEB-INF/messages_en.xml" etc. Note that message definitions in a previous resource bundle will override ones in a later bundle, due to sequential lookup.

This MessageSource can easily be used outside of an ApplicationContext: It will use a DefaultResourceLoader as default, simply getting overridden with the ApplicationContext's resource loader if running in a context. It does not have any other specific dependencies.

so the fix is to provide the path.

from

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource()
{
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

to includeing the path on `setBasename()`

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource()
{
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: but it doen't work i have tried. if you have complete example please with us.

Comment: What version of Thymeleaf and spring boot? This worked with Thymeleaf 2.1.x and spring boot 1.3.x

Comment: Well i am using Thymleaf 3.0.0 and spring-web 4.3.4

Comment: Probably why then I understand Thymeleaf went under a large rewrite for 3.0.

Comment: Sorry @ndrone not getting you last comment.
But you are right it may work with Thymleaf 2.1.x.
Now in my case Message resource is working fine if i access in Controller.
For Example : if i execute `http:ip:port/mypage/home?lang=en` or `http:ip:port/mypage/home?lang=fr` 
it works fine.
But the only problem is on HTML page when i try to access by Thymleaf. e.g `#{page.title}`

Comment: I have found my mistake my templateEngine wasn't set as @Bean.